# how to make screen only display white and black color in android for all app

Tags: android, colors

I want to make app look like Ultra Power Saving Mode (galaxy s5). it change screen only display black and white color. I don't know how to make it.
Can anyone give some advice or information about how to do this?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: y do you want to change in black nd white ?who said it will save power ?

Comment: Ultra Power Saving Mode in Galaxy do that. Maybe 2 colors are more save energy than full color. DO you know how to make it? thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
// Create a paint object with 0 saturation (black and white)
ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
cm.setSaturation(0);
Paint greyscalePaint = new Paint();
greyscalePaint.setColorFilter(new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm));
// Create a hardware layer with the greyscale paint
v.setLayerType(LAYER_TYPE_HARDWARE, greyscalePaint);
```

use these code to the root layout.

[image]

Comment: This is long time to see your answer. Maybe that is what I am looking for

Comment: I don't know what is the problem but, it doesn't work in my Nexus 6p. I put android: hardwareAccelerarion: true in the manifest. But it seems v.isHardwareAccelerated() returns false always.

Comment: Hi, is it possible to make one of child views stay its own color?

Comment: You applied setLayerType() to "v". "v" is an object of what that allows you to switch to grey scale for the entire app?

Answer (score 2):

If you are designing your entire app to look black/white or grayscale, the easiest thing to do is to define your color palate in res/values/colors.xml to include only black/white/gray colors when designing and coloring your app.

If you have a fully colorized app and wish to flip everything on a setting or have images that you wish to grayscale, I would recommend using a user preference boolean and define a method in your onCreate.

To turn your ImageViews into black and white, you can use:

```
ColorMatrix colorMatrix = new ColorMatrix();
colorMatrix.setSaturation(0);
ColorMatrixColorFilter colorFilter = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(colorMatrix);
imageView.setColorFilter(colorFilter);
```

For all Views, you should be able to apply a Tint to it to remove the colors: 
using the android:backgroundTint, or to change the color properties of buttons or checkboxes.

Answer (score 0):

Your basic idea is flawed.

Samsung had to build off of Android to make the `Ultra Power Saving Mode.` This isn't something that you can just create yourself simply by creating a black and white app.

### [Here is a desription of Ultra Power Saving Mode ....](http://www.phonedog.com/2014/06/25/trying-out-the-galaxy-s5-s-ultra-power-saving-mode/)

`What happens if the battery drains away? Some start turning things off, like Wi-Fi or Bluetooth, or even just activate Airplane Mode. Lower the screen's brightness. A bunch of random, individual things all meant to give the battery just a little bit longer of a push.`

`Samsung wanted to make that easier, and take things a bit further, by including their Ultra Power Saving Mode in the Galaxy S5. It does all of those things, with some tweaks. Instead of lowering the screen's brightness only, it actually turns it grayscale, and gives you a black-and-white representation of your phone's display. So even if you do use an app, like respond to an important text message, it'll remain grayscale. It turns off things like Bluetooth and Wi-Fi. It will also turn off your phone's data connection when the display is off, and switch back on when you start using your phone.`

`Even the lock screen changes, as you'll no longer see the weather report there, and Samsung's fancy animation is gone, replaced by a simple indicator as to how to unlock the device. Once you do, the next screen is just a short six-item list of pre-approved applications that you can use while in the mode.`

So  there are MANY things that when all combined will save the battery of the device; changing the screen from color to gray-scale will not be a major improvement. Also, depending on how you implement it, you can actually be making the performance worse!!

Samsung has tweaked almost everything and tested everything to make sure that all the tweaks in that mode actually save battery power. That isn't going to be something that you will be doing by yourself.

Comment: Thank sir for respone. As I know, in AMOLED screen, display B&W color save energy then full color. And I want to know the technical how to make a screen display greyscale color. Not for save energy! Thanks alot!

Answer (score -3):

Go to your settings. Click on power saving mode. Turn on gray scale mode.