# Is there a way to programmatically make the screen monochrome?

Tags: android, colors, screen

I know there's a monochrome mode in the developer options, but is there a way to make the screen monochrome programmatically?(i don't want to turn on that specific setting. I just want any way to make the screen monochrome.)

Comment: Check out this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24900803/how-to-make-screen-only-display-white-and-black-color-in-android-for-all-app

Comment: @ChrisStillwell that just makes the app monochrome. I want the entire system to be monochrome(the homescreen, the app drawer, and any other apps).

Comment: [In this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26645768/1827254), you can display a component on top of everything (on top of the all system view). It remains active as long as the app is running (even in the background). So mixing this solution with the one from @ChrisStillwell, you should be able to achieve what you want. Basically the idea is to add a filter on top of the entire screen (and not on the root layout of your app). However there is maybe a better way to do that.

Comment: @Eselfar So i combined the 2 answers, but this results in the view being drawn below the system ui. So the wallpaper is black and white, but the status bar, the app icons and launcher is not.

Comment: ok, after playing with this, i dont think this is the solution. This just changes the colour of the view itself. I don't think you can use a view as a "filter" to change the colour of the views/activities below it.